# Adding integer with index -2

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I went through a interview where I was asked to add 2 integers with -2 index i.e. (-2) power i for the ith bit . I gave the following answer but was told that this answer is not efficient and wrong.I don't agree with the in-efficient comment but may agree with the incorrectness.

The way I added was taking a carry of -1 if the sum of 2 bits is more that equal to 2 because the adjacent bit has the opposite sign. And if adding 2 bits is -1 i make it one and take a carry of 1 to the adjacent bit.

Do any one see any issues with the code?

```
struct Results solution ( int A[], int M, int B[], int N ) {
    struct Results result;

    int min =M;
    int max = M;

    int i=0;
    int sum;
    int carry = 0;

    if(N<M)min = N;
    if(N>M)max = N;

    result.C = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * max);

    for(i=0;i<min;i++){
        sum = A[i] +  B[i] + carry;
        if(sum >= 2 ){
            if(carry == 0 ) 
                carry = -1;
            else 
                carry = -carry;
            sum = sum-2;
        }
        else if(sum == -1){
            sum = 1;
            carry = 1;  
        }
        else{
            carry=0;
        }
        result.C[i] = sum;
    }

    if( M > N){
        result.L = M;
        for(i=N;i<M;i++){
            sum = A[i]+carry;
            if(sum >= 2 ){
                if(carry == 0 ) carry = -1;
                else carry = 1;
                sum = sum-2;
            }
            else if(sum == -1){
                sum = 1;
                carry = - carry;  
            }
            else{carry=0;}
            result.C[i] = sum;
        }
    }

    if( N > M){
        result.L = N;
        for(i=M;i<N;i++){
            sum = B[i]+carry;
            if(sum >= 2 ){
                if(carry == 0 ) carry = -1;
                else carry = -carry;
                sum = sum-2;
            }
            else if(sum == -1){
                sum = 1;
                carry = 1;  
            }
            else{carry=0;}
            result.C[i] = sum;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int A[]  = {0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1};
    int B[]  = {0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1};
    solution (A,15,B ,12 );
}
```

Comment: Should probably ask on CodeReview.

Comment: ok i will do that i dont get help here

Comment: So you defend your code saying that it does the wrong thing fast enoough?

Comment: The sample test cases which were provided went through successfully. So i am not sure if i missed any edge cases. Also i say its not in-efficient because its a O(N) solution N been the no. of bits you cannot add faster without going through all bits. Btw it was a online test

Comment: The min/max initialisation is buggy.

Comment: It is indeed inefficient. You are using one int for one bit.

Comment: No that was input format which came from the question

Comment: Isn't this really called "base -2" or perhaps "radix -2" instead of "index -2"?

Comment: The test case would have been binary numbers, storing it in int array was your choice.

Comment: no the declaration of solution was given to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem 1

You say you use ***a carry of -1 if the sum of 2 bits is more that equal to 2*** but in one of your cases you have the code:

```
        if(sum >= 2 ){
            if(carry == 0 ) carry = -1;
            else carry = 1;
            sum = sum-2;
        }
```

This will set the carry to 1, not -1.

You could also argue that this code could be written more efficiently as:

```
        if(sum >= 2 ){
            carry = -1;
            sum = sum-2;
        }
```

### Problem 2

What happens if we add {1} and {1}?
You will return a length of 1 and a result of {0}, but the answer should be {0,1,1}. (1+1=-2+4)
In other words, you may need to return more bits than the maximum of the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

O(1) solution:  Table lookup.

If you know the number of bits per input, a 2D lookup table does it real fast.  If not, you can still do a bunch of bits at a time with it.